# Angular Material doesn't style for some reason

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, angular-material

I added angular material to my MVC application. When I load the page I see no errors but for some reason is not styling either. I added necessary dependency to my package.json file, added link to css theme in my Layout.cshtml, added necessary mapping in systems.config.js. Created a separate material.module.ts with all material modules. Referenced it from app.module.ts. Imported css from my site.css file. Added material content, but still I see no styling. What am I missing?

Here is my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "~5.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~5.0.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.10",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  }
```

Layout.cshtml has link to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

systems.config.js

```
 map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            'app': 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
            'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',

            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',

            '@angular/cdk': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/a11y': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/bidi': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/coercion': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-coercion.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/collections': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-collections.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/keycodes': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-keycodes.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/observers': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-observers.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/overlay': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-overlay.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/platform': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-platform.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/portal': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-portal.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/rxjs': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-rxjs.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/table': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-table.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/scrolling': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-scrolling.umd.js',

            '@angular/cdk/accordion': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-accordion.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/layout': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-layout.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk/stepper': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-stepper.umd.js',    

            'hammerjs': 'npm:hammerjs',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
```

here is my material.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { BidiModule } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
import { ObserversModule } from '@angular/cdk/observers';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { PlatformModule } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { ScrollDispatchModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { CdkStepperModule } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';

import {
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      MatAutocompleteModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatButtonToggleModule,
      MatCardModule,
      MatCheckboxModule,
      MatChipsModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatDialogModule,
      MatDividerModule,
      MatExpansionModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatGridListModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatListModule,
      MatMenuModule,
      MatNativeDateModule,
      MatPaginatorModule,
      MatProgressBarModule,
      MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      MatRadioModule,
      MatRippleModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatSidenavModule,
      MatSliderModule,
      MatSlideToggleModule,
      MatSnackBarModule,
      MatSortModule,
      MatStepperModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatTabsModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatTooltipModule
  ],
  exports: [
      MatAutocompleteModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatButtonToggleModule,
      MatCardModule,
      MatCheckboxModule,
      MatChipsModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatDialogModule,
      MatDividerModule,
      MatExpansionModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatGridListModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatListModule,
      MatMenuModule,
      MatNativeDateModule,
      MatPaginatorModule,
      MatProgressBarModule,
      MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      MatRadioModule,
      MatRippleModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatSidenavModule,
      MatSliderModule,
      MatSlideToggleModule,
      MatSnackBarModule,
      MatSortModule,
      MatStepperModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatTabsModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatTooltipModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";

import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { CommunityListComponent } from "./community/community-list.component";
import { CommunityService } from "./community/community.service";
import { CommunityTypeService } from "./communityType/communityType.service";
import { CommunityDetailComponent } from "./community/community-detail.component";
import { LocationService } from "./location/location.service";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, MaterialModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and site.css has rerefence to the theme

```
@import '/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

This is the content of my page.

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                This is the expansion title
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
                This is a summary of the content
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>

    </mat-expansion-panel>

    <span class="done">
        <button mat-fab>
            <mat-icon>check circle</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </span>
```

what am I missing?

Comment: This is the correct path to theme: `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but it cannot find it.

Comment: Hey @Crazy Jack I jst checked back and @Faisal is right, that is the right import. Add the line to `style.scss` and it should work

Comment: Are you using scss at all?

Comment: I don't use scss. I added it to my site.css file which is under root->content folder. My app is under root->app and that's why it cannot find the file when I use ~@angular

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming):

> If you're using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line in your styles.css file:
>
> `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`
>
> Alternatively, you can just reference the file directly. This would look something like:
>
> `<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`
>
> The actual path will depend on your server setup.
>
> Finally, if your app's content **is not** placed inside of a mat-sidenav-container element, **you need to add** the mat-app-background class to your wrapper element (for example the body). This ensures that the proper theme background is applied to your page.

So ensure that you are importing the theme stylesheet correctly, and also that you place the `mat-app-background` class to your wrapper element (body or other).